# gpsd doesn't work automatically after restarting the system

Tags: 20.04, usb, systemd, gps

I’m hoping someone on this forum will be willing to help me get some USB-based GPSs to work with gpsd on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. A friend and I have the same problem with two different model GPSs on fresh installs of Ubuntu. After plugging the GPS units into our systems, the devices are available as tty devices, but gpsd doesn’t have them in its devices list and cgps displays a time out message. We are using gpsd version 3.20.

We can get gpsd to work by manually stopping the gpsd socket and manually starting gpsd with these commands:

```
sudo systemctl stop gpsd.socket
 
gpsd -N -D3 /dev/ttyUSB0   (on my friend’s system)
or 
gpsd -N -D3 /dev/ttyACM0  (on my system)
```

I’m a retired IT guy with decent experience in Windows and a smidgin of experience in Linux.  I can follow directions if anyone can direct me what to do next to figure out why gpsd doesn’t work automatically.

I’ve researched this problem on the gpsd user mailing list and I’ve seen a few posts that indicate that other people have had similar problems on Ubuntu. The typical response on the gpsd mailing list is that they think the issue is with systemd and they wash their hands of the problem. I am hoping that someone on this forum can be more helpful than just saying “study how systemd works and get it working.”

More Details:

My GPS is a VK-162 G-Mouse USB GPS Dongle. Its vendor ID is `1546` and its product ID is `01a7`. Ubuntu maps my GPS as device ttyACM0.

My friend’s NEO-7M-0-00 GPS has a vendor ID of `10c4` and a productid of `ea60`.  Ubuntu maps my friend’s GPS to ttyUSB0.

According to `lsusb`, Ubuntu recognizes my GPS as a u-blox 7 device:

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 1546:01a7 U-Blox AG [u-blox 7]
```

`lsusb` indicates that Ubuntu recognizes my friend’s GPS as a CP210x UART Bridge device:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 10c4:ea60 Silicon Labs CP210x UART Bridge
```

Here are the udev rules for the two GPS’s in /lib/udev/rules.d/60-gpsd.rules:

```
u-blox AG, u-blox 7 [linux module: cdc_acm]
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1546", ATTRS{idProduct}=="01a7", SYMLINK+="gps%n", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="gpsdctl@%k.service"

Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x Composite Device (Used by Holux m241 and Wintec grays2 wbt-201) [linux module: cp210x]
ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea60", SYMLINK+="gps%n", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="gpsdctl@%k.service"
```

Powering up my Ubuntu system with the GPS unplugged and running systemctl shows one gpsd related entry:

```
gpsd.socket              loaded active listening GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon Sockets
```

After plugging the GPS into my system, systemctl finds these gpsd related processes:

```
gpsdctl@ttyACM0.service  loaded active exited       Manage ttyACM0 for GPS daemon
system-gpsdctl.slice     loaded active active       system gpsdctl.slice
gpsd.socket              loaded active listening  GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon Sockets
```

We can get gpsd to work by stopping the gpsd socket and starting gpsd manually with these commands:

```
sudo systemctl stop gpsd.socket 
gpsd -N -D3 /dev/ttyUSB0   (on my friend’s system)
```

or

```
gpsd -N -D3 /dev/ttyACM0  (on my system)
```

After stopping the socket and starting gpsd manually, gpspipe -w shows the devices in gpsd’s devices list.  E.g. on my system:

```
al@Al-HP-Linux:~$ gpspipe -w
{"class":"VERSION","release":"3.20","rev":"3.20","proto_major":3,"proto_minor":14}
{"class":"DEVICES","devices":[{"class":"DEVICE","path":"/dev/ttyACM0","activated":"2021-05-16T17:48:25.283Z","native":0,"bps":9600,"parity":"N","stopbits":1,"cycle":1.00}]}
{"class":"WATCH","enable":true,"json":true,"nmea":false,"raw":0,"scaled":false,"timing":false,"split24":false,"pps":false}
{"class":"DEVICE","path":"/dev/ttyACM0","driver":"NMEA0183","activated":"2021-05-16T17:48:26.082Z","native":0,"bps":9600,"parity":"N","stopbits":1,"cycle":1.00}
```

My linux login is in the dialout and tty groups.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else has the same problem with their GPS, I'm posting the solution that got my GPS working on my Ubuntu system and on my friend's Ubuntu system,without having to run manual commands after restarting Ubuntu.

I can reboot my system with a GPS plugged in and gpsd just works.  I can unplug my GPS and plug in a different GPS (or vice-versa) and the system detects the change and gpsd uses the new GPS.

The fix was to add some entries to the /etc/default/gpsd configuration file. Here are the entries that I added to /etc/default/gpsd:

START_DAEMON="true"

USBAUTO="true"

If your /etc/default/gpsd file has a DEVICES line like the one below, you should change the DEVICES line to an empty string.
I.e., if you have something like this:
DEVICES="/dev/ttyUSB0"
Change it to this:
DEVICES=""

Note that you have to edit the /etc/default/gpsd file as root, so start your editor using sudo.  Not sure if it was necessary, but after I saved my changes, I rebooted my Ubuntu system.

I hope this info helps other GPS users.